# How to display php code in html page dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

Please, I have terms of use page and I want to seed using laravel with the store name like this;

```
'<p>Welcome to <?php printf(core()->getCurrentChannel()->business_name) ?>. We reserve the right... </p>
```

So I want it to display like this : Welcome to ufanstore. We reserve the right...

The store name can change if the admin rename his/her store name. my question is how can I display this so that it can change dynamically ?

Comment: Do you mean that the name can change at any time, and then the user web views have to be refreshed automatically, without any user action?

Comment: No, until admin change....  and if the admin change the name, it should display dynamically. I don't know how to display it ,I have tried this ```{!! $page->page_content !!}``` but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one need, I resolved my issue with the following approach;

I seeded my html code like this `<p>Welcome to {Name}. We reserve the right to update or modify these Terms of Use at any time without prior notice</p>`

in my controller I perform this action `$pageContent = str_replace('{Name}', core()->getCurrentChannel()->business_name, $page->page_content);`

then in my blade, I can access `$pageContent` with {!! $pageContent !!}

Answer (score 0):

Laravel use php blade template so you can use this brackets `{{ }}`  if you want to print code coming from database as text only .
and if you have multiple line text or you have html code in database and you want to print it you can use `{!! !!}` in your example you can use the below code

```
<p>Welcome to {{core()->getCurrentChannel()->business_name}} . We reserve the right... </p>
```

and if you want to print it in native php code use:

```
<?= core()->getCurrentChannel()->business_name ?>
```

> Note : Make sure you are fetched data from controller currently by print data coming from database using `print_r()` to be `print_r(core()->getCurrentChannel())` if it's not getting data recheck your code again.